# How can I make a text be truncated when it exceeds the size of a div container?

Tags: html, css

I have two div containers that are placed next to each other. Both have the same size. Now I have a paragraph in the left container and I don´t want the paragraph to have a line break. Also, the container shouldn´t change its size.

Around these two div containers is another one with `display: flex`, so that its two children are placed next to each other. For the paragraph, I have the following CSS styles.

```
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
   width: 300px;
```

It works for me like this, but I don´t want to give the exact size in px for the width. I want that it is the normal size of the div container and that this size can´t be exceeded. If it is, the container should remain the same size and the text of the paragraph should be cut off.

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. Use the [live demo](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) feature of the question editor.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what exactly you're trying to do, but have you tried the CSS `text-overflow: ellipsis;` property?
Let me show you how you can implement that:
HTML

```css
.mother_div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.mother_div>div {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.text-holding_div {
  background-color: red;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.text-holding_div p {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.second_child {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="mother_div">
  <div class="text-holding_div">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc tincidunt, ex vel bibendum egestas, tellus dui fringilla tellus, eget imperdiet odio quam at nisi. Phasellus ultrices non diam quis consequat. Vivamus eget sapien eget nunc consequat fermentum
      vitae nec neque. Nam magna lorem, convallis id euismod sit amet, egestas sed tortor. </p>
  </div>
  <div class="second_child"></div>
</div>
```

This way you don't have to hard code a fixed width to the paragraph tag, and as a bonus, the text cut off looks neater.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is working now. The only issue that is left, is that the text just gets cut of without  the three dots "..." to indicate that it´s just cut of.

Comment: If the 'three dots - ...' (ellipsis) isn't showing, just crosscheck that the `text-overflow: ellipsis;` property is styled on the tag that holds the text you want to cut off. If it's done correctly, then I might need more context to pinpoint what could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

And if you, for example, want to allow two lines avoid using `white-space: nowrap` and consider using `line-clamp: 2` like so:

```css
.mother_div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.mother_div>div {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.text-holding_div {
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}

.second_child {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="mother_div">
  <div class="text-holding_div">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc tincidunt, ex vel bibendum egestas, tellus dui fringilla tellus, eget imperdiet odio quam at nisi. Phasellus ultrices non diam quis consequat. Vivamus eget sapien eget nunc consequat fermentum
      vitae nec neque. Nam magna lorem, convallis id euismod sit amet, egestas sed tortor. </p>
  </div>
  <div class="second_child"></div>
</div>
```